# change an object with ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, django-viewsets

im building a project with DRF and im trying to understand how the modelviewset is working,
im sending a url like this:
`localhost/do_somthing/object_id/`
and route it with :

```
router.register('do_somthing', views.do_somthing, basename='do_somthing')
```

the view is:

```
class do_somthing_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        obj= Object.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        user = self.request.user
        if user == obj.user:
            obj.att= True
            obj.save
            return self.queryset
        else:
            None
```

the object model looks like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="realted_user")
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    att= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

the problem is that the att never changes and still set to False
is there any way better i can get to change the attribute and return the object
BTW ive tried to return an unauthorized response when its not that user but i cant return a response
if someone can please help me or can even suggest a better way to do that
that would help me alot
thanks

i am trying to present an object and when its presented by the correct user change an attribute of that object

Answer (score 1):

first of all
you need to call the `save` method and change `obj.save` to `obj.save()`
and don't forget to add params in the path for kwargs.
I advise overriding get or update for this not `get_queryset`
for returning `unauthorized` I strongly recommend creating a custom permission class inheriting from `IsAuthenticated` and overriding `has_object_permission`
it will do the entire thing for you
it makes sure it is user's
it will return 403 if it's not(that happens in drf default exception handler)
if you don't want to do that and still want a 403 response do this:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class do_somthing_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        if user == obj.user:
           ...
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied("some proper message")
```

I still **STRONGLY** advise you to use a custom permission class and move logic part out of `get_queryset`

Comment: @ShTuj 
if i want to delete an object i need to do it in permissions to or it can be in the view?
i have a model with two boolean fields and two users need to ask for delete it in order for the object to be deleted 
i cant do t with a DELETE request because the object will be deleted how you would recommend me to do it?

Comment: @ShTurj 
you can do it in the view and I advise you to do so. override it and apply the extra logic in it